# Pyramid/Python/SQLAlchemy encoding hell

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm in quite a pickle here.

So I'm using SQLAlchemy and Pyramid for a web app. One of the functions of this app is parsing input from a form which is passed to a Ruby parser over a XML-RPC bridge.

The issue arises when I try to use my renderer to return the JSON of a newly parsed object.

Here's the error, followed by details:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 93: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Setup**

**DB setup**

Collation: `utf8_general_ci`

**Model**

```
class Citation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'citations'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True}
    authors = relationship("Author", secondary=author_of, backref='citations')

    possible_matches = relationship("Citation", secondary=similar_to,
        primaryjoin=citation_id==similar_to.c.citation_id1,
        secondaryjoin=citation_id==similar_to.c.citation_id2
        )

    def __init__(self, citation_dict=None):
        self.__dict__.update(citation_dict)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Citation %d: %s (%s)>" %\
               (self.citation_id, self.title, self.year)

    @property
    def json(self):
        attrs =\
            ['pubtype', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'doi', 'url', 'address',
             'booktitle', 'chapter', 'crossref', 'edition', 'editor',
             'translator', 'howpublished', 'institution', 'journal',
             'bibtex_key', 'month', 'note', 'number', 'organization',
             'pages', 'publisher', 'location', 'school', 'series', 'title',
             'type', 'volume', 'year', 'raw', 'verified', 'last_modified',
             'entryTime', 'citation_id']
        struct = { 'authors' : [a.json for a in self.authors] }
        for attr in attrs:
            struct[attr] = getattr(self, attr, None)

        struct["auth_string"] = " ".join([a.toString() for a in self.authors])
        return struct
```

**View**

```
@view_config(route_name='citation_add', request_method='POST', renderer='pubs_json')
def citation_add(request):
    raw = request.body
    citation = parser.parse(raw)[0]

    return citation.json
```

**Renderer**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import customjson
import os
from pyramid.asset import abspath_from_asset_spec

class PubsJSONRenderer:
        def __init__(self, info):
                """ Constructor: info will be an object having the the 
                following attributes: name (the renderer name), package 
                (the package that was 'current' at the time the 
                renderer was registered), type (the renderer type 
                name), registry (the current application registry) and 
                settings (the deployment settings dictionary).        """


        def __call__(self, value, system):
                """ Call a the renderer implementation with the value 
                and the system value passed in as arguments and return 
                the result (a string or unicode object).  The value is 
                the return value of a view.         The system value is a 
                dictionary containing available system values 
                (e.g. view, context, and request). """
                request = system.get('request')
                if request is not None:
                        if not hasattr(request, 'response_content_type'):
                                request.response_content_type = 'application/json'

                return customjson.dumps(value)
```

**customjson.py**

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from decimal import Decimal
class ExtJsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    '''
    Extends ``simplejson.JSONEncoder`` by allowing it to encode any
    arbitrary generator, iterator, closure or functor.
    '''
    def default(self, c):
        # Handles generators and iterators
        if hasattr(c, '__iter__'):
            return [i for i in c]

        # Handles closures and functors
        if hasattr(c, '__call__'):
            return c()

        # Handles precise decimals with loss of precision to float.
        # Hack, but it works
        if isinstance(c, Decimal):
            return float(c)

        return JSONEncoder.default(self, c)

def dumps(*args):
    '''
    Shortcut for ``ExtJsonEncoder.encode()``
    '''
    return ExtJsonEncoder(sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False,
            skipkeys=True).encode(*args)
```

**The stack trace**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File     "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 242, in __call__
     response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 217, in invoke_subrequest
     response = handle_request(request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 160, in toolbar_tween
     return handler(request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
     response = handler(request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
     reraise(*exc_info)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
     response = handler(request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
     response = view_callable(context, request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 329, in attr_view
     return view(context, request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 305, in predicate_wrapper
     return view(context, request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 377, in rendered_view
     context)
   File "/var/site/sitvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/renderers.py", line 418, in render_view
     return self.render_to_response(response, system, request=request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/renderers.py", line 441, in render_to_response
     result = self.render(value, system_values, request=request)
   File "/var/site/siteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/renderers.py", line 437, in render
     result = renderer(value, system_values)
   File "/var/site/renderers.py", line 30, in __call__
     return customjson.dumps(value)
   File "/var/site/customjson.py", line 38, in dumps
     skipkeys=True).encode(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 203, in encode
     return ''.join(chunks)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 93: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Return from the parser**

We feed in

```
Allen, C. 1995 "It isn't what you think: a new idea about intentional causation." Noûs 29,1:115-126
```

We get back a dict object like this from the parser:

```
{'title': '\\\\"It isn\\'t what you think: a new idea about intentional causation.\\\\"', 'journal': 'No\\\\xc3\\\\xbbs', 'author': 'Allen, C.', 'number': 1, 'volume': 29, 'date': '1995', 'type': 'article', 'pages': u'115\\u2013126'}
```

**Tried**

Because the app is operating in a virtual environment I felt alright with hopping over to `page.py` and changing the default encoding from `ascii` to `utf-8`.

I've tried encoding and decoding and adding `charset=utf8&use_unicode=1` to my SQLAlchemy URL to no avail.

My suspicion is that the problem lies with the `ensure_ascii=False` option in the `customjson.py` file. In fact, the documentation for the Python 2.7 JSON encoder says the following:

> if ensure_ascii is False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.

Setting `ensure_ascii=True` seems to work around the error. Given that the default encoding for the json encoder is already `utf-8` I'm not sure setting it manually will help. I need those unicode characters, so I'm not really sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: *The issue arises*. **What** issue arrises? You didn't include an error message in your question. What happens, what should happen instead? For what input?

Comment: @MartijnPieters d'oh, I forgot to include the stack trace. Thanks for catching me!

Comment: So what does the view return and pass to the rendered? Can you include a sample `repr()` output for such a value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The view creates a citation object based off of what's returned from the parser.

Comment: Yes, but *something in that structure* is a byte string with non-ASCII bytes. I'm trying to pinpoint that something so I can help you fix that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, evidently enter's not a newline in the comments. I added the `repr` to the post above.

Comment: You have a few too many ``\`` in that value, I think. But note the `journal` key; where did that string come from? You can only JSON encode  this with an explicit encoding mentioned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's certainly the case: the string I'm feeding in (which I added to the question) has the character `û`. But then, the default encoding for the JSON encoder when not specified is already `utf-8` by the documentation. Will adding that explicitly help?

Comment: I have no idea how many backslashes are really there from what you got back from the parser. There certainly appear too many. Yes, the `json.dumps()` function already should take care of bytestrings encoded in UTF-8. It certainly works like that for me, in any case, so I cannot reproduce your issue with this dictionary and your code, no matter how many backslashes I remove.

Comment: Something that strikes me as odd is that `customjson.py` seems to call the server's version of `encoder.py` instead of that of the virtualenv: `"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py"`

Comment: That's fine; the virtualenv doesn't have copies of everything in the stdlib nor does it need to.

Comment: In any case, is there any way you could log the value of `value` in `PubsJSONRenderer.__call__`? The value you posted (the one with all the backslashes) cannot throw the exception as posted. What point release of Python 2.7 is this? I cannot find any changelog entries that look relevant, but I might have more luck reproducing this with a specific version.

Comment: So it turns out I'm a huge dope and missed an unnecessary call to `JSON.stringify` that was being made client side on submission that seemed to escape the characters. The python was all correct. I'll answer this in a second. Thanks for your help, @MartijnPieters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a call to `JSON.stringify` on the client side that was escaping the troublesome characters. Removing this lead to the python working as desired.